# JQuery pass selected value to Ajax parameter

Tags: jquery, filtering

I used [this pagination script](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/10/pagination-with-jquery-php-ajax-and.html) and wanted to implemented filtering by options using jq's ajax request, data will filtering with selected value when user trigger it, the page will load `all` data by default when first loaded.

I tried to pass `txt_filter` to ajax's parameters object that is ready send to PHP to processing data, but below script is not working when I select filtering options.

How could `txt_filter` be pass to function loadData when user select it?

```
// Filtering Options

<form id="formfilter" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div style="padding-bottom:6px;">
       Genre:<br />
       <select id="filterGenre">
        <option value="all" selected="selected">All</option>
        <option value='1'>Education</option>
        <option value='2'>Entertainment</option>
        <option value='3'>Documentary</option>
       </select>
   </div>
</form>


// Get filtering value stored in variable
var txt_filter;
$("#filterGenre").change(function(){
    txt_filter = $('#filterGenre').val();
    //alert(txt_filter);
});


// Pass filtering value to filterGenre
function loadData(page){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_network_programs.php",
        data: { page: page, filterGenre: txt_filter },
        success: function(msg){
            $("#inner-main_content3").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
                $("#inner-main_content3").html(msg);
            });
        }
    });
}
loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
  .
  .
  .
//blah blah codes not relevant...
```

Thanks.

Comment: got your answer for ya :) see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is assuming your PHP script, is setup to handle filterGenre already.
If you haven't done this, then of course its not going to work.....you need to have an SQL query on the backend to check $_POST['filterGenre'], and apply relevant query.

Anyway....assuming you have done that, and know what Im talking about..
then proceed as follows..

Just change your loadData function to take two arguments...
a page and a filter argument...

```
function loadData(page, filter){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_network_programs.php",
    data: { 'page': page, 'filterGenre': filter },
    success: function(msg){
        $("#inner-main_content3").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
            $("#inner-main_content3").html(msg);
        });
    }
});
```

}

Then run the function inside your onchange handler...

```
$("#filterGenre").change(function(){
var txt_filter = $('#filterGenre').val();
loadData(1,txt_filter);
});
```

Then update the function at the bottom of the page, for the first time the page loads.....

```
  loadData(1,1);
```

Now I assume when they click a paginate button you want to run this function with whatever current select filter is applied... so that the user can paginate the results with filter....based on the link to your code...just do this...

```
  $('#container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
  var page = $(this).attr('p');
  var txt_filter = $('#filterGenre').val();
    loadData(page, txt_filter);
  });
```

**EDIT**

The first time your page loads up, you need to specify all records...
So based on what you told me about your php page...
This should work..

```
loadData(1,all);
```

Comment: My phpscript is ready to accepted `filterGenre`, I will try yours and report back to you

Comment: its works awesome!! but when the page first loaded, its not showing all records by default, any idea?

Comment: Thats because its passing 1 as the filter, so its filtering a genre.....you should just change the firsttime load to loadData(1,0), and then change your PHP on the other side to check for a 0 and then not filter..and just do a select *.  I would post an example but I don't know what your php code looks like....hopefully you understand what I mean

Comment: my default value to load all records is `all`

Comment: ok then change your 'firstime' loadData(1,1) to loadData(1,all), that should do it

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved lot of my time

Answer (score 0):

> as per my requirement i need to submit a select option to my back end
>   to store the selected option in a combo box so to pass i used jquery
>   as follows

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submid").click(function() { // loginForm is submitted
var conceptName = $('#sel_opt').find(":selected").val();// to send the selected combo box option 
$('#sel_opt').attr('name',conceptName);//passing option value to form combobox 
$.ajax({

url: "urls", 
data:{
"sel_opt":$("#sel_opt").attr("name"),
},

}); // ajax

});//click
});


</script>

</HEAD>

<BODY>
<select id="sel_opt" name="">    
<option>1</option>   
<option>2<option>   
<option>3</option>  
</select>



</BODY>
</HTML>
```